# php mysql search when search key as two or more words combined without space

Tags: php, mysql

i want to implement a search in which if the search key is 'goodmorning' (instead of 'good morning') it should return all the rows having 'good morning' or 'goodmorning' anywhere in description column.

Comment: Good Luck! No one here is going to build that query for you. Have you at least tried anything?

Comment: You need some more examples of what you're attempting here. For example, would your search return a row with "goo dmorning"?

Comment: yes Davey, as you told even it should return if there is a row like "goo dmorning". If possible if it was a misspelled search key also.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do with `replace()` and `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(description, ' ', '') like '%goodmorning%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a array of words to be added if found. Something like this.

```
$words = array(
   'goodmorning' => 'good morning'
   // Paste all the words you need
);
```

Then when you receive the search string to check for it there and if found pass the 2 search params. Something like this.

```
$search = $_GET['keyword'];

$searchParams = array();
$searchParams[] = 'description LIKE "%' . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $search) . '"';

if(isset($words[$search])) {
    $searchParams[] = 'description LIKE "%' . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $words[$search]) . '"';
}

$query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE' . implode(' OR '$searchParams));
```